# phpMyAdmin & MySQL-Community Server | Create user error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed a new MySQL-Community Server but then I try to create a user it comes the following error message in phpmyadmin:

> 1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei 'REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_' in Zeile 1
>       CREATE USER 'jts3servermod'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '***';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO
>   'jts3servermod'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS
>   0;

Comment: a i forgot: 
    Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server-Typ: MySQL
    Server-Version: 8.0.12 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
    Protokoll-Version: 10
    Benutzer: root@localhost
    Server-Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: You can add ^^ comment in question.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL unexpectedly changed a couple of things with the release of version 8.0.11, and it sounds like you're affected by this, which is filed as a [phpMyAdmin bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14217). It will be fixed but there isn't yet a new phpMyAdmin release that resolves this. In the meantime, a workaround would be to enter the SQL commands manually through the phpMyAdmin SQL tab.